# How to add images in Photo Album using different Models

Tags: php, mysql, yii

hello guys i want to create a gallery using two tables

album table and photo table

'album' holds the (album_name) and 'photo' holds the (pictures)

this is my form

```
            //this is for my album name to album table
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'album_name'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'album_name'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'album_name'); ?>

            //this is for the pictures to the photo table
            <?php   $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
                'name' => 'photo_name',
                'model' => $model,
                'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png',
                'duplicate' => 'File is already added!',
                'remove'=>Yii::t('ui','Remove'),                    
                'denied' => 'Not images', // useful,
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
                'class' => 'btn btn-success fileinput-button',),
             )); ?>
```

this is my controller

```
            public function actionCreate()

            {
                $model = new Album;
                $model2 = new Photo;


                if (isset($_POST['Album'])) {

                    $model->attributes = $_POST['Album'];
                    $model2->attributes = $_POST['Photo'];

                    $photos = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('photo_name');

                    if (isset($photos) && count($photos) > 0) {

                         foreach ($photos as $pic) { 
                           echo $pic->name.'<br />';
                            if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/assets/photos/'.$pic->name)) {
                                $model2 = new Photo();
                                $model2->attributes = $_POST['Photo'];
                                $model2->photo_name = $pic->name;   
                                $model2->photo_id = NULL;
                                $model2->isNewRecord= true;
                                $model2->save();    
                                } else {
                                echo 'Cannot upload!';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ($model->save())
                        $this->redirect(array('index'));
                }
                $this->render('create', array(
                    'model' => $model,

                ));

            }
```

am i doing it the right way? because when i run this code its only adding the album_id and album_name in the album table
the photo table is empty. Also the actionCreate is in the AlbumController

Comment: Why are you uploading photos to assets? Assets are temporary folder that can be recreated at any time.

Comment: Are the photo files saved in your folder?

Comment: Yes the pictures are being saved in the folder